# writing sql procedure

Tags: sql-server

I wrote a sql procedure to get the name of the physician by entering the Eid in sql server.

```
create procedure doca(@eid int,@pname varchar  output)
as
begin
select @pname =p.name
from physician p
where p.eid =@eid
end
```

I used the procedure by following way

```
declare @pname varchar
exec doca 1,@pname output
print @pname
```

when I enter 1 I want to get the name of the physician whose `eid` is 1.

in this case it should be **"John Dorian"**
but this procedure prints just **"J"**

whats wrong with my code?

Comment: [NEVER declare `varchar` etc. without defining a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). Also, please [always specify the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the `@pname as varchar(x)`  where x is the length of the `Physician.Name` column.  Make the change in both pieces of code.

Declaring the variable as just `varchar` indicates you only want a single character at most.